# Why is editted wrong?

Tags: pronunciation, vowels, consonants, letters-of-the-alphabet

The general rule is that when we have *vowel + consonant + vowel* we should double the consonant, in order to properly pronounce the whole word.

The examples include: *submitted* , *shipping*, etc.

So why don't we say *editted* and *editting*?

Why are *edited* and *editing* correct?

Comment: All I can say is that doing otherwise earned me a ruler-smack on the knuckles from my English teacher. Even after reading all of the answers here, multiple googling attempts, and asking people, this is still valid. "editted" is wrong *because* it is wrong, and for no other reason at all.

Comment: @PcMan Indeed.  English doesn't have *rules*.  It has *rulers* - and they punish you when you get it wrong, lol.

Comment: @J... Hahaha. When I started learning German and Czech I realized how English rules are almost nonexistent. The words are just spelled how they are with no way to know without knowing beforehand.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> In a word with 2 or more syllables, double the final consonant ONLY if the word ends in 1 vowel + 1 consonant AND the final syllable is stressed.  ([source](https://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/Doubling-the-final-consonant-before-adding-ed-or-ing))

So submit =  /səbˈmɪt/ becomes submitted

But edit =  /ˈedɪt/ becomes edited

Comment: In BE, there are the verbs _cancelled_, _labelled_, and many others which contradict this rule.

Comment: Rules in language are often like observing a natural phenomenon. You observe, then you make rules. If something break the rule, you modify the rule. Very seldom it's possible to change what you observe to fit the rule.

Comment: @rexkogitans That famously only applies to the consonant 'l' which doubles in BE regardless of stress (but subject to being preceded by a single vowel, of course).

Comment: James's answer is a good general rule, but keep in mind that there are quite a few exceptions not only in BE but also in US English. For example, words like "focus," "travel," and "shovel" optionally double the final consonant in US English.

Comment: Re *"words like "focus," "travel," and "shovel" optionally double the final consonant in US English."*: Can you back that up with a source? [Wiktionary says](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/travel#Verb), for example (my emphasis),  *"travel (third-person singular simple present travels, present participle travelling or* ***(US) traveling***, *simple past and past participle travelled or ***(US) traveled)"*** (I am not sure how to interpret that.)

Comment: @PeterMortensen I remember particularly noticing that the British game *Traveller* was not spelled the same as in America.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. *focussed* is also acceptable in BE (it may be listed an alternative form, but I prefer it)

Comment: @Peter: Yeah, I would say that "focused, traveled, shoveled (labeled, canceled)" are strictly US English whereas "focussed, travelled, shovelled (labelled, cancelled)" are strictly British English. However, in the USA, _the use of US English_ is optional — if you use a few British English spellings here and there, I'd bet nobody would call you on it. That doesn't make them "US English spellings," but it does make them "socially acceptable spellings _of_ English, _in_ the US." :) (As opposed to, like, "foccused, traveld, shuvveled.")

Comment: m-w.com (which generally adheres to US English standards) indicates that doubling the final consonant is optional for all of those words. I unfortunately don't know much about what is considered correct or acceptable in British English.

Answer (score 12):

James K gives a full answer for American English.

However, one might ask why "editted" is not seen even in British English, which has several examples that contradict the stress-based rule (as pointed out by rexkogitans). The reason for this is that in British English it depends also on the consonant in question. Compare these quotes from Fowler's *Modern English Usage* (not actually all that modern as I only have an old edition to hand, but at least it gives the traditional BrE usage; I have edited to omit unnecessary examples).

For -ll- vs -l-:

> Final *l* is treated differently in British, but not American, usage from most final consonants, the rule being to double it, if single, in inflexions & in some derivatives, irrespective of the position of the accent.

For -tt- vs -t-:

> Words of more than one syllable follow the rule for monosyllables [doubling only if they immediately follow a single-letter vowel] if their last syllable is accented; but otherwise they do not  double it.

For -pp- vs -p-:

> Words of more than one syllable follow the rule for monosyllables if their last syllable is accented; they also double the *p* if they have a clear ă or ŏ as opposed to the obscure sound in *jalap* & *gallop*, or if, like *horsewhip* & *sideslip*, they are compounded with a monosyllable; but otherwise they do not double it except *worship*.

Comment: The description of t/tt here just follows the normal rule.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Yes, that is the point: BrE uses the "normal rule" for T, but not for L. So I needed to quote what my source says on both letters to justify that claim.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime, typo? "edited" is seen, "editted" is not

Comment: @Buster well spotted, thanks!

Comment: @EspeciallyLime Thank you for your answer. Can you please edit your question to add examples for each part?